# Using the "Write" method inside the handler, the header remains empty, however, this is not true for the "ServeFile" function, why does this happen?

Tags: go

I'm learning about golang handlers and have some misunderstandings. It is associated with the Response header. When I use `http.ServeFile` function it will populate response header as I expect. Here is the code with the output:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()

mux.HandleFunc("/nesto", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./ui/static/js/main.js")
    fmt.Println("Header:", w.Header())
})

http.ListenAndServe(":4000", mux)
```

The output:

```
Header: map[Accept-Ranges:[bytes] Content-Length:[224] Content-Type:[application/javascript] Last-Modified:[Thu, 05 Jul 2018 13:44:05 GMT]]
```

To me it's expected behavior, since it has `http.ResponseWriter` as the first parameter and will use the `Write` method internally to write to the response body. Comments regarding this method are as follows:

```
// If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls
// WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data. If the Header
// does not contain a Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type set
// to the result of passing the initial 512 bytes of written data to
// DetectContentType. Additionally, if the total size of all written
// data is under a few KB and there are no Flush calls, the
// Content-Length header is added automatically.
```

So, totally normal behavior for me.

But when I use the `Write` method directly, the `Header` remains empty.

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()

mux.HandleFunc("/nesto", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Some message."))
    fmt.Println("Header:", w.Header())
})

http.ListenAndServe(":4000", mux)
```

The output:

```
Header: map[]
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the Header be filled in, after all, the documentation itself (comment regarding the method) says so?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation describes the headers written to the network, not the response writer [Header()](https://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header).

The documentation is a little sloppy.  The call to Write before WriteHeader triggers the actions described in documentation.  The actions do not necessarily execute in the first call to Write:

- The server waits for the application to write 512 bytes of data or for the handler to return before calling DetectContentType.
- The server buffers a few KB of data. If the handler returns and that buffer has not been flushed to the network, then the server adds a content length to the headers written to the network.

See the [code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ebb572d82f97d19d0016a49956eb1fddc658eb76/src/net/http/server.go#L422) for more details.

You see the content length and content type headers after the call to  [ServeFile](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeFile) because ServeFile explicitly sets these headers in the response writer [Header()](https://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header).  The content length is set to the size of the file on disk.  The content type is set using the file name [extension](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Ext).